# Can I use an AIR Component/Library for developing iOS App using Xcode?

Tags: ios, flash, air

I want to develop a Flash Live Stream Player on iOS. As you known, Flash does not supported on iOS platform. I searched Google, but all results are about the [ANE (Air Native Extensions)](http://www.adobe.com/cn/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html).
Is there any way that building **Xcode usable** component/control/library/framework from Flash/Flex/AIR? Or any other solutions that playing flash on iOS?
Any advice would be grateful, thanks.

Comment: Here are your options concerning Flash and IOS: You can build Adobe AIR apps for IOS. To do this you must use the proper IDE (Flash Builder, Flash Develop, mxml command line compiler, etc. ... but not Xcode). Adobe AIR apps can also use native code via the ANE's. So you could write an Objective C library with Xcode, and then create an ANE that uses it. But then to build that app that takes advantage of that ANE you go back to a Flash/Flex based IDE (not Xcode) and write Actionscript to build an app. Hope that helps.

Comment: @SunilD. Thank you, I've known this way, but my app is larger and uses a lot of Objc/C++ frameworks, so it will be a nightmare if transfer to Flash using ANE :(

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, there's not much recourse for you on IOS. The only way (out of the box) to show any type of Flash content on IOS would be via an Adobe AIR app. Theoretically, you could write Objective C code to play a Flash stream (such a library does exist, I don't recall the name -- a coworker was trying to use it). But the results were sketchy with live video and the solution was a big hack to work around Apple's limitations.

Comment: @SunilD. Thank you very much. I find some apps/libraries can play flash, even live streaming, such as animation library for Cocos2D, mobile VLC, etc. I'm doing researches.